# How can I code a more simplified VirtueMart purchase/checkout sequence?

Tags: joomla, e-commerce, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I'm almost positive this topic has been addressed somewhere because my question feels so rudimentary. That said, I haven't had any luck searching, so here's the question:

I am using VM to sell ONE item only (digital download), and the default "Add to Cart" then "View Cart" 2-step process is cumbersome. What I want is the ability to change "Add to Cart" to a button that says "Purchase" (I don't need help here) and change the coding for the button so that ONE item is added to the cart and the user is taken automatically to the checkout page.

If there is a simple URL format to achieve this, that's my preference, because then I could just manually code out my own product page (like a Joomla article, rather than in VirtueMart) and then add my own "Purchase" button. However, if I have to modify PHP, that's fine too, I just need to get pointed in the right direction.

If someone could direct me to the proper resource for this? I can't believe I haven't been able to find something so rudimentary, and I suspect I'm not using the right search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you are using Joomla 1.5

here is an extension: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-related-products/14458

see demos, I'm sure it will be fine for you

Compatible with VirtueMart 1.1.x (VM2 version is ongoing)

5/5 votes from 6 users

Comment: That's a really nice extension, it is very well done and would accomplish exactly what is being asked.

Comment: I've never heard of it before, but I'm looking at it right now and it looks nice. I was hoping for a programmatic solution, but I'm willing to give this a try. Actually, I can think of a couple clients who could benefit from this installation.

Comment: This is potentially a great solution, but it's a 49.00 Euro solution. Mainly it looks like the cost is coming from their efforts to make one-page signup and purchase... and that's a level ABOVE what I actually need.... All I NEED is the ability to create a link that adds the item to the cart and sends the viewer to checkout, and that sure seems like a one-or-two-line coding solution, rather than a 49 Euro fancy solution. I'm gonna seriously consider these guys, but if anyone can provide the simple code solution, that would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: I think it's not "a one-or-two line solution". Obviously VM is very mature application and things like adding an item to chart is done in VM component after tones of validation code. Of course I can be wrong but the best thing could be to look into VM plugins and search for an event dispatcher function like "onAddToChart()"

Comment: Thanks! I'm probably just going to purchase this. Quick and easy (and looks nice too)..... :-)

Comment: I'm astonished just how very non-trivial the answer to my original question was. I was firmly convinced I was overlooking something tiny, and it turns out making VM do what I wanted took quite a bit of effort. The entire project is done now, thanks in part to the great Stack Overflow community. The client is ready to launch, and they're really happy with the one-page extension you recommended!